# Simple.Data subtract days from date time in where clause

Tags: c#, sql-server, simple.data

I am using Simple.Data (version 0.19.0.0) against a SQL Server back end database and would like a query such as the one below to take 25 days from a date to compare against the date now;

```
DateTime dtNow = DateTime.Now.Date;        

var pool = db.Pools.FindAll(db.Pools.Status == 1
              && db.Pools.EndDate - 25 > dtNow)
           .Select(db.Pools.AllColumns());
```

I have tried using DATEADD but get an error that the function is not recognised, I guess because the column name is not the first parameter of the method.

Is this kind of thing possible in Simple.Data, or should I ignore the date in the query and perform the check in a foreach loop following?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overcame the problem by using a where clause on my query with a >= and < date range as suggested in [how to search by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23565498/simple-data-orm-how-to-search-by-date) question.

Answer (score 0):

Try like that;

```
DateTime dtNow = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-25).Date;        

var pool = db.Pools.FindAll(db.Pools.Status == 1
              && db.Pools.EndDate > dtNow)
           .Select(db.Pools.AllColumns());
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that changes the whole logic of the query. Thanks for trying though.